# Vaadin 23 Ui.navigate from another thread

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

When I try to navigate a user asynchronously from the server-side via `@Push` like:

```
ListenableFuture<JobApplicationMatrix> listenableFuture = // some Async method invocation

var ui = UI.getCurrent();
listenableFuture.addCallback(jobApplicationMatrix -> {
     ui.access(() -> {
              
          ui.navigate(CandidateComplianceApplicationView.class, new RouteParameters(CandidateComplianceApplicationView.APPLICATION_UUID_PARAMETER, candidateApplicationUuid));
              
     });
}
```

it is not working as expected. `CandidateComplianceApplicationView` is a secured View. When I execute `ui.navigate` from `ui.access` the system moves me to the Keycloak login page. Looks like the system doesn't understand that the user is logged in. So, is this possible to navigate to the secure view from `ui.access` and if so, what am I doing wrong here?

I also tried to change `@PermitAll` to `@AnonymousAllowed` on `CandidateComplianceApplicationView`. In such case the system moves me to the correct page but the actual content of the `CandidateComplianceApplicationView` is not rendered at all.

**UPDATED**

I use

```
@Push(transport = Transport.LONG_POLLING)
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible because the SecurityContext is bound to the thread

Comment: Thanks! The biggest concern here also, that the `CandidateComplianceApplicationView` is not rendered even in case I configure it with `@AnonymousAllowed`

Comment: I've never tried to navigate with a Push and I could imagine that this doesn't work. Instead of navigate you could try to use UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation

Comment: I think this is a valid question, but I wonder, if this is good UX - has the user "ordered" this "surprise navigation" at some point and is just twiddling thumbs till it happens?

Comment: `ui.getPage().setLocation` works fine, I already use it instead of `navigate` but from time to ime users claim that they are with no reasons move to the home page when clicking something… so I think I have a conceptual issue somewhere in the code with @Push and user session.. The biggest issue is  - that I don't see any issues at log..

Comment: Also, one more question - should I use `UI.setCurrent(ui)` in `ui.access(() -> {}` code block? Does this make any sense?